# Persian numbers in Flutter App displayed english

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, farsi

I'm developing a flutter app in Persian language. I used a Persian font that changes all Persian alphabets but it doesn't change numbers. They remain like this: 1, 2, 3 ,..
Is there any solution to change all numbers in app?

used font works in editors. when I have a String in app including '۱،۲,..' it displayed correctly. Challenge is when user enters value in textfield or response returns from server.

Comment: I think the problem is with the font you are using. maybe you are not using the correct font file that has persian numbers

Comment: I think you are right. I tried another font numbers changes. but it's strange. when keyboard is in persian language numbers are correct. Thank u

Comment: When you type using persian keyboard, it is actually typing real persian number characters which are different from English number characters, you should use a version of your font that shows English number characters as Persian number characters. What is the name of the font you are using?

Comment: oh yes... Font name is 'Estedad'. I saw comments below the downloaded link some people said that what a pity it doesn't support numbers :(

Comment: thank you. It solved by using FD version of font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using FD version of font.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a function to replacing the numbers cause for some people it's seem imposibble to import a pesian / arabic numbers as data for a Text() so this function could help but you need FD version of whatever font you are using :

```
String replaceFarsiNumber(String input) {
  const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

  for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
    input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
  }

  return input;
}

main() {
  print(replaceFarsiNumber('0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'));  // ==>  ۰-۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to convert Persian to English or reverse.

https://pub.dev/packages/persian_number_utility

Answer (score -3):

To ensure consistent display of numbers in your Flutter app with a Persian font, you can use the flutter_localizations package along with the intl package to handle number formatting and localization. Here's how you can achieve this:

for pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Run flutter pub get to fetch the packages.
Import the required packages in your Dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Set up localization delegates and supported locales in your MaterialApp widget. In the supportedLocales parameter, include the Locale for Persian (fa):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('fa'), // Persian
      ],
      title: 'My App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Use the NumberFormat class from the intl package to format numbers with Persian digits. You can create a helper method that converts numbers to a localized Persian format:

```
String formatNumber(int number) {
  final numberFormat = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('fa');
  return numberFormat.format(number);
}
```

When displaying numbers in your app, use the formatNumber method to ensure that they are correctly formatted:

```
final myNumber = 1234567;
final formattedNumber = formatNumber(myNumber);
print(formattedNumber); // Output: ۱,۲۳۴,۵۶۷
```

I tried it on iOS and Android everything is working stable

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since many of your last seven answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: thank you. It solved by using FD version of font

Comment: Can you check my answer as correct answer?